# How to split an array of elements into groups by the value of a certain property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array:

```
[{
    name: "A1"
    series: "A series"
}, 
{
    name: "A2"
    series: "A series"
}, 
{
    name: "B1"
    series: "B series"
}, 
{
    name: "C1"
    // series is not defined
}]
```

I want to split this array into multiple arrays grouped by their values of the series property. I want to arrive at something like the structure below. But as long as the result contains arrays grouped by their values of the series property, the exact format does not matter.

```
[
    {
        series: "A series",
        items: [{
            name: "A1"
        },
        {
            name: "A2"
        }]
    },
    {
        series: "B series",
        items: [{
            name: "B1"
        }]
    }
    {
        items: [{
            name: "C1"
        }]
    }
]
```

Here is my best attempt:

```
private groupProductsBySeries = (devices: IItem[]): IProductGroup[] => {
    const seriesSymbols: any = new Map();
    const itemsBySeries: any = [];
    const series: any = [];

    devices.forEach((device) => {
        let symbol = seriesSymbols.get(device.properties.series);
        if (!symbol) {
            symbol = Symbol();
            seriesSymbols.set(device.properties.series, symbol);
        }

        Array.isArray(itemsBySeries[symbol])
            ? itemsBySeries[symbol].push(device)
            : (itemsBySeries[symbol] = [device]);
    });

    seriesSymbols.forEach((value: any, key: any) => {
        series.push({
            name: key,
            items: itemsBySeries[value],
        });
    });

    return series;
};
```

I'm thinking that maybe it is needlessly complex. And when I try to add types, I get complaints from the TypeScript compiler.

Question:

- Is there a better way to solve this problem?
- If not, how would the code above look with types successfully added?
  If not

**Edited after adigas comment**

Comment: Expected output is invalid. Do you want an array of objects?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit to fix and clarify expected outcome. I want some output where items are grouped by the series property. I think an array of objects would be nice, but other formats can also be acceptable.

Comment: Also add commas where needed -- your code contains syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function groupProductsBySeries(devices) {
  const series = Array.from(new Set(devices.map(item => item.series)));
  return series.map(item => {
    const series = item ? { series: item } : null;

    return {
      ...series,
      items: devices.filter(device => device.series === item)
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: I ended up with something very similar to the above, where `a1` refers to the original array: `Array.from(new Set(a1.map(obj => obj.series))).map(series => ({ series, items: a1.filter(obj => obj.series == series).map(({ name }) => ({ name })) }))`. We both have pretty much identical solutions, so I thought yours should stand.

Comment: I updated my solution. In previous when series is not persist, the name was undefined in the result

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score -1):

You could write a generic function that accepts any field and group by them. Something like below could help.

```js
data = [{
    name: "A1",
    series: "A series"
}, 
{
    name: "A2",
    series: "A series"
}, 
{
    name: "B1",
    series: "B series"
}, 
{
    name: "C1",
    // series is not defined
}]

data1 = [{
    name: "A",
    series: "A series"
}, 
{
    name: "A",
    series: "A series"
}, 
{
    name: "B",
    series: "B series"
}, 
{
    name: "C",
    // series is not defined
}]


function groupByField(data, field){
    const groupedByObject = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
        const rest = Object.keys(val).reduce((newObj, key) => {
            if(key !== field){
                newObj[key] = val[key]
            }
            return newObj;
        }, {});
        if (acc[val[field]]) {
          acc[val[field]].push(rest);
        } else {;
          acc[val[field]] = [rest];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {})

    //Return the reduced object from above if want in Object format. If wanted array, return the below statement

    return Object.keys(groupedByObject).filter(a => a!== "undefined").map(key => ({[field]: key, items: groupedByObject[key]}))

}

a = groupByField(data,"series");
console.log("Grouped by series")
console.log(a);



b = groupByField(data1, "name");
console.log("Grouped by name")
console.log(b);
```

Comment: I would have used reduce as well but it seems OP wants an array.

Answer (score -1):

I'd iterate over the `name` and `series` properties of each object, with the `series` defaulting to the empty string if empty, putting values onto an object whose properties are the `series` being iterated over, and that series' associated object (with the nested `items` array). If a series doesn't exist on it yet, create it if needed (and assign a `series` property if necessary), otherwise just push the `{ name }` to it.

At the end, take the object's values to get your desired output:

```
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'A1',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'A2',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'B1',
        series: 'B series',
    },
    {
        name: 'C1',
    // series is not defined
    },
];
type outputItem = {
    series?: string,
    items: Array<{ name: string }>,
};
const groupedObj: { [series: string]: outputItem } = {};
for (const { name, series='' } of arr) {
    if (!groupedObj[series]) {
        groupedObj[series] = { items: [{ name }] };
        if (series) {
            groupedObj[series].series = series;
        }
    } else {
        groupedObj[series].items.push({ name });
    }
}
const output = Object.values(groupedObj);
console.log(output);
```

Translated into Javascript:

```js
"use strict";
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'A1',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'A2',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'B1',
        series: 'B series',
    },
    {
        name: 'C1',
    },
];
const groupedObj = {};
for (const { name, series = '' } of arr) {
    if (!groupedObj[series]) {
        groupedObj[series] = { items: [{ name }] };
        if (series) {
            groupedObj[series].series = series;
        }
    }
    else {
        groupedObj[series].items.push({ name });
    }
}
const output = Object.values(groupedObj);
console.log(output);
```

This object structure is pretty peculiar, though. It would probably be a lot easier to work with a single object, whose keys are the `series`, and whose values are arrays of `name` values:

```
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'A1',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'A2',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'B1',
        series: 'B series',
    },
    {
        name: 'C1',
    // series is not defined
    },
];
const output: { [series: string]: string[] } = {};
for (const { name, series='' } of arr) {
    if (!output[series]) {
        output[series] = [name];
    } else {
        output[series].push(name);
    }
}
console.log(output);
```

Translated to Javascript:

```js
"use strict";
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'A1',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'A2',
        series: 'A series',
    },
    {
        name: 'B1',
        series: 'B series',
    },
    {
        name: 'C1',
    },
];
const output = {};
for (const { name, series = '' } of arr) {
    if (!output[series]) {
        output[series] = [name];
    }
    else {
        output[series].push(name);
    }
}
console.log(output);
```